# Is coating basement walls with water-proof cement a proper method to water-proof your basement?

Tags: basement, waterproofing

I'd like to make my basement more livable (i.e. build a bathroom and bedroom down there). It is "finished" but not to a level where someone could live there comfortably. The air is certainly more humid than in the rest of the house, as the house was built around 1920.

Is coating basement walls with water-proof cement a proper method to water-proof your basement? If not, what are more proper methods for achieving better air quality and less humidity down there?

Comment: Probably would want some type of vapour barrier or water proofing(usually used for leaks on the outside).  For the humidity, would want ventilation(maybe just a fan).  All the air from  above sinks down when it cools and feels damper, and stays in the basement.

Comment: Assuming the walls are some form of concrete or block, waterproofing paint or cement is not very effective long-term.  Look at basement encapsulation, which seals the space with heavy duty plastic film.  If there are active water leaks, that is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean with "proper"
There are several reasons that normally, the water barrier is installed on the outside

1. Walls can work like a wick und pull moisure up. With a barrier on the outside you don't have the water in your walls, so ther is no "wikk effect"
2. on the outside, the water/moisture presses the waterproofing material against the wall. If applied on the inside, there is the risk that at some point it will peel off the wall and break
3. There is normally no one on the outside rubbing against the waterproofing

That said: It can be done, but it has to be done properly. We've had an elevator shaft where water was ingressing from the ground and causing all kinds of faults. A contractor spent several days (the area was less than 2m by 2m) cleaning and preparing the old surface and applying cement with special additives. As far as I know: it held. But it was just one flat area with a very defined ingress problem. I'm not sure if this would work in another setting.

Answer (score 1):

> Is coating basement walls with water-proof cement a proper method to water-proof your basement?

It can be. Are you having water ingress problems?

---

> If not, what are more proper methods for achieving better air quality and less humidity down there?

A dehumidifier with a built-in pump will work wonders for a basement. You might even consider running two depending on how low you need the humidity to be.

I used to have a dehumidifier which had to be manually emptied; it was the bane of my existence. Spend the money and get one with a built-in pump.

Answer (score 0):

Moisture is either coming up from below (a rising water table) or its coming from the surrounding ground water in the saturated soil, or both.

If it comes up from a rising water table, it will enter the living space from below through the crack between the foundation wall and slab.

If it comes from the surrounding ground water, it COULD enter the living space through the wall, especially if the EXTERIOR side of the foundation wall is not sealed properly.Coating the interior wall surface allows the moisture to penetrate the wall and create problems on the interior side of the wall.

Either way the moisture enters the living space it will need to be collected and disposed. I think the best way to collect it is on the exterior side of the foundation wall in drainrock and a perf pipe laid 6”-8” below the interior basement slab.

To keep the subsurface water from seeping through the wall, I recommend installing a moisture barrier on the exterior side of the foundation wall and install a 2” thick plastic mesh on the wall to allow water to flow down to the perf pipe. If dirt is allowed to be backfilled against the wall, the dirt could hold the moisture giving it a chance to seep through the wall.

Once collected it needs to be disposed by extending a solid pipe over an embankment or in a collection well and pumped away.

This may be the most expensive method of solving the problem, but it’s sure to work.